# How to compare a string value with values in enumeration in SRL

Tags: enums, srl, blaze-advisor

as I am very new to blaze advisor and SRL. I am trying to compare a value with the elements in enumeration by Iterating it. below is the code.

```
    for each  CompanyList do
```

{

if(anApplicant.employementDetail.organisation=it) then{
print("companies" it).
break.

}

But I am getting error saying

```
Error: 'type' and 'string' are incompatible types.  main.advprom    /assignProject [New Repository]/assignProject Folder/Testing    line 718    Blaze Advisor Compilation Problem
```

I can say that this is valid error, but I wanted to know how I can compare a value using Structure rule language.

Answer (score 1):

Use Casting

> if(foo = (it as a string)) then
> {
> }

Even after this you will face another issue, regarding unsupported keyword.
( ***`break`*** )

There is No such thing like ***`break`***, remove it.